# Create an array and set values

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

I'm trying to create an array:

```
var rgsFilenamesType = ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.char.ptr);
var rgsFilenames = new rgsFilenamesType(1);
rgsFilenames[0] = 'rawr'; //OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, 'parent.lock');
```

however it keeps telling me:

```
Exception: expected type pointer, got "rawr"
```

My goal is to pass it to this funciton here:

```
dwError = RmRegisterResources(dwSession, rgsFilenames.length, rgsFilenames, 0, null, 0, null);
```

declaration of this function:

```
/* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
* DWORD WINAPI RmRegisterResources(
*   __in_      DWORD dwSessionHandle,
*   __in_      UINT nFiles,
*   __in_opt_  LPCWSTR rgsFilenames[ ],
*   __in_      UINT nApplications,
*   __in_opt_  RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS rgApplications[ ],
*   __in_      UINT nServices,
*   __in_opt_  LPCWSTR rgsServiceNames[ ]
* );
*/
var RmRegisterResources = lib.rstrtmgr.declare('RmRegisterResources', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.unsigned_long, // DWORD
    ctypes.uint32_t, // DWORD
    ctypes.unsigned_int, // UINT
    ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.char.ptr, 1), // LPCWSTR
    ctypes.unsigned_int, // UINT
    ctypes.ArrayType(struct_RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS, 1), // RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS
    ctypes.unsigned_int, // UINT
    ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.char.ptr, 1) // LPCWSTR
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to check, but the "rawr" assignment should be something like

```js
rgsFilenames[0] = ctypes.char.array()("rawr");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @paa man. @John-Galt showed me how to get it to work.

He did this to make the array:

```
let strings = ['rawr', 'blah'].map(s => ctypes.char.array()(s));
let a = ctypes.char.ptr.array(strings.length)();
strings.forEach((s, i) => { a[i] = s; });
```

and then in the function declare we changed `ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.char.ptr, 1)` to `ctypes.char.ptr.array()`

and it worked! :)

im having a hard time doing the same with a custom type though.

like i changed arg declare from `ctypes.ArrayType(struct_RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS, 1)` to `struct_RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS.ptr.array()` but then Im not sure how to create an array populated with such elements. I tried this:

```
let rgApplicationsNonCData = struct_RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS.array(2)();
rgApplicationsNonCData[0].dwProcessId = 123;
rgApplicationsNonCData[0].ProcessStartTime = BLAHOBJECT;

rgApplicationsNonCData[1].dwProcessId = 123;
rgApplicationsNonCData[1].ProcessStartTime = BLAHOBJECT;
console.log('rgApplicationsNonCData:', rgApplicationsNonCData)

let rgApplications = struct_RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS.ptr.array(rgApplicationsNonCData.length)();
console.log('rgApplications:', rgApplications)
```

its not throwing any errors, but is this right way? how to check its contents?

actual code to create the RM)UNIQUE_PROCESSS array:

```
  let rgApplicationsNonCData = struct_RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS.array(2)();
  rgApplicationsNonCData[0].dwProcessId = 123;
  rgApplicationsNonCData[0].ProcessStartTime = new struct_FILETIME();
    rgApplicationsNonCData[0].ProcessStartTime.dwLowDateTime = 111;
    rgApplicationsNonCData[0].ProcessStartTime.dwHighDateTime = 222;

  rgApplicationsNonCData[1].dwProcessId = 123;
  rgApplicationsNonCData[1].ProcessStartTime = new struct_FILETIME();
    rgApplicationsNonCData[1].ProcessStartTime.dwLowDateTime = 111;
    rgApplicationsNonCData[1].ProcessStartTime.dwHighDateTime = 222;

  console.log('rgApplicationsNonCData:', rgApplicationsNonCData);

  let rgApplications = struct_RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS.ptr.array(rgApplicationsNonCData.length)();
  console.log('rgApplications:', rgApplications)
```

`console.log('rgApplications:', rgApplications)` and `console.log('rgApplicationsNonCData:', rgApplicationsNonCData);` dont show anything other than `CData {length:2}`